# file diff compare with itself

Tags: file, shell, command-line, diff

I have a file with many tcl processes, but most of the processes seem to be the same or at least have very minor differences.

```
proc x {
   set ...
}
proc y {
   set ...
}
```

Is it possible with linux diff or any other file comparison tool to compare a file to itself, given some line numbers? i.e.diff file:10-20 file:50-60.

Comment: `diff -u <(sed -n '10,20p' file) <(sed -n '50-60p' file)`

Comment: thank you Etan, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Inspired me to try the less succinct perl version: `diff -u <(perl -ne 'if ($. > 10 && $. < 20) {print $_}' file) <(perl -ne 'if ($. > 50 && $. < 60) {print $_}' file)`

Comment: I *think* (but I don't do perl) that you could do `{print $_} if ($. > 10 && $. < 20)` to golf it slightly but yeah, that's the idea.